# Transform returned result set to an appropriate JSON format

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have below table, This table has millions of records based on timestamp.

[image]

When I run below query,

```sql
Select datetime, Rupee, Yen 
from currency 
where datetime between value1 and value2
```

I get following result

[image]

Now it gets converted to JSON format, I get below result,

```
[
  {
    "datetime": "2019-02-16T10:40:00.000Z",
    "Rupee": 10,
    "Yen": 60
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2019-24-16T10:50:00.000Z",
    "Rupee": 30,
    "Yen": 70
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2019-02-16T10:55:00.000Z",
    "Rupee": 40,
    "Yen": 80
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2019-02-16T10:58:00.000Z",
    "Rupee": 50,
    "Yen": 90
  }
]
```

**BUT I want to transform the result to below format,**

```
[
  {
     "currency": "Rupee",
      "timeseriesdata": [
        ["2019-02-16T10:40:00.000Z",10],
        ["2019-24-16T10:50:00.000Z", 30],
        ["2019-02-16T10:55:00.000Z", 40],
        ["2019-02-16T10:58:00.000Z", 50]
      ]
  },
  {
    "currency": "Yen",
      "timeseriesdata": [
        ["2019-02-16T10:40:00.000Z",60],
        ["2019-24-16T10:50:00.000Z", 70],
        ["2019-02-16T10:55:00.000Z", 80],
        ["2019-02-16T10:58:00.000Z", 90]
      ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do it using MYSQL query/stored procedure/functions ? is it even possible ?

Pls note I can transform it in Node/Javascript but ***returned result set would contain million of records with hundred of currencies in real life scenario***. So I don't think it makes sense to convert it in Node/Javascript. OR I don't know how should I deal with this scenario.

Comment: I don't think, that there is a way to get rows as arrays. Depending on how you want to use the data, there might be a way to use it in its original form.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), espesially "5. Some Additional Suggestions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of [json_object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object), [json_array](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) and [json_arrayagg](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) 
  FROM (SELECT json_object('currency', 'Rupee', 
                           'timeseriesdata', json_arrayagg(json_array(datetime, rupee))) AS obj 
          FROM currency
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT json_object('currency', 'Yen', 
                           'timeseriesdata', json_arrayagg(json_array(datetime, yen))) 
          FROM currency
       ) x;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bYOdvSs9).

Comment: This is giving weird result set

Comment: @micronyks, I've added a fiddle. Why do you think, it's weird?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. it worked now. I really appreciate your answer and efforts but here it looks you are making an individual queries for each column eg. Rupee, Yen. As I already mentioned in my actual DB, I have at least 100 currencies (eg. Ruppe, Yen, Pound etc) and for each currency I have million of records. Is there any way to make it dynamic ? Also the problem would be, for me, I have separate DBs for each customer. `Your answer is really great by the way`.

Comment: Probably this would help you understand (up to some extend) what I mean : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852739/how-to-execute-same-queries-with-different-column-names-against-different-databa

Comment: Thanks for your kind feedback. The problem is, that your currencies are stored in different columns instead of different rows. Usually it requires you to name each column (btw: the accepted answer in the linked question does this, too) explicitly. You could also use dynamic SQL (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table) for an example). I'll try something different, but this will take a few hours as I'm busy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yeah probably that is what I'm looking for (but not sure). Yeah pls take your time but if you could help me.

Comment: One more thing: do you use MySQL 8?

Comment: How can I check it? I'm using mysql db from AWS RDS service. SO my mysql is on AWS.

Comment: Just do a `SELECT version();`

Comment: It is showing `5.7.38-log`

Comment: Ok, didn't work. You'll have to go the dynamic SQL path :-(

Comment: Can you pls help me? In real implementation it is giving me below result : {
            `"json_arrayagg(obj)": "[\"{\\\"datapoints\\\": [[\\\"2018-04-16 16:01:00.000000\\\", 19.510161666667]], \\\"currency\\\": \\\"Rupee\\\"}\", \"{\\\"datapoints\\\": [[\\\"2018-04-16 16:01:00.000000\\\", -166.767015], [\\\"2018-04-16 16:04:00.000000\\\", -166.782305]], \\\"currency\\\": \\\"pound\\\"}\"]"
        }`  why is it `givng json.arrayagg(obj)` as key ? and also as you can see it is giving `\\\`  back slash everywhere. any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248401/discussion-between-mihe-and-micronyks).

Comment: Can you pls pls pls help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944429/stored-procedure-to-get-a-desire-result-set-to-improve-performance-mysql ?