# Stored procedure to get a desire result set to improve performance - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I'm completely new in mysql and struggling to write a store procedure to get a required result set.
As you can see below are the tables I have,

[image]

I'm using **node & express** api to connect to **mysql** database. Then I make individual query to get desire result using **for loop**. As I deal with million of records, it becomes slow eventually making queries from node api to mysql every time. **I want to improve the performance**.

**Basically I want to get the **timeseries** data for **each currency** for **given period****.

Currently what I'm doing is as below,

---

**1)** first get all currencies for which I want to get time series data

***Payload** to get currencies.*

```
{
  "currencies":[ "Rupee", "Dollar"]
}
```

***query to get relevant result***

> Select name, tablename from Currency_table where name IN (${currencies})

> NOTE: I can't include **refernece_col** as it is sensitive detail in real scenario and it can not be exposed to outside world

The Resultset that I get is as below and I store it in a variable called **currency_result_set**,

[image: ![![enter image description here]

---

**2)** Then, I loop through each record and prepare a query to get **reference_col** column first for each record,

```
  for ( const record of currency_result_set){
        // apply some login I generate below payload
  }
```

***Payload** to get **reference_col**

```
{
  "starttime": "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z",
  "endtime": "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z",
  "currencies": [
    {
          "name": "Rupee",
          "tablename": "rupee_table"
    },
    {
          "name": "Dollar",
          "tablename": "dollar_table"
    },   
  ]
}
```

get this payload and prepare below query to get **reference_col** for each record

**query**

```
select  reference_col, name, tablename  from rupee_table
                                    where name = "Rupee"
                                    and tablename = "rupee_table" 
Union All 

select  reference_col, name, tablename  from dollar_table
                                    where name = "Dollar"
                                    and tablename = "dollar_table"
```

**Resultset**

[image]

---

**3)** finally by using for loop again and applying some logic, I generate below queries

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM( 

    SELECT json_object(
        "name", "Rupee",
        "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime), C1))) AS obj 
        FROM rupee_table 
        where datetime 
        between "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z" AND "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z"
                                       
    UNION ALL 
                                
    SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) as RESULT FROM( SELECT json_object(
        "name", "Dollar",
        "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime), C2))) AS obj 
        FROM dollar_table 
        where datetime 
        between "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z" AND "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z"
        
) x
```

And finally the **desire result set** that I get as below,

```
[
    {
        "name": "Rupee",
        "value": [
            [
                1627166760,           // this is timestamp of the date comes using UNIX_TIMESTAMP function
                10
            ],
            [
                1627166820,
                20
            ],
            [
                1627166880,
                30
            ],
            [
                1627166940,
                40
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "signalname": "Dollar",
        "datapoints": [
            [
                1627166760,
                50
            ],
            [
                1627166820,
                60
            ],
            [
                1627166880,
                70
            ],
            [
                1627166940,
                80
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

and I feed this result to **Highcharts** and it draws the relevant lines/charts.

AS you can see, I loop through multiple times to get desire result. As I deal with million of records, preparing query again n again and sending it to mysql every time, has become very slow.
I want to know how to write a stored procedure to get desire result.

Comment: Recently I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862732/transform-returned-result-set-to-an-appropriate-json-format to prepare the final query.

Comment: I don't think, that you can do much about performance (other than indexing) since the DB would have to query each table, regardless of whether this is done in a loop by you or with a UNION. The schema design is not optimal for RDBMS. Why don't you store your data a in a single table? Then, a single SELECT would be probably enough.

Comment: Yes, I know DB structure may not be proper but unfortunately it is already designed that way and I can't modify/control it for some reason and I will have to live with it.

Comment: I see. One question: in the image ref_column is in Currency_Table. In 2) you select ref_column from e. g. rupee_table, but your image doesn't show ref_column there. Can you clarify this? Would it be possible to select ref_column from Currency_Table in a stored procedure?

Comment: so basically, as you can see, `ref_column` in `currency_table`  only indicates: for `rupee` timeseries data, pls refer `ref_column` (which is `c1`) from `tablename` (which is `rupee_table`). So to get `rupee` timeseries data, I will go to `rupee_table`, pick `c1` column and according to given time range, I will query data.. So basically, `currency_table` gives you more idea that where to look up to get timeseries data for any currency. I hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

- A MySQL Stored Procedure won't necessarily help with performance.  One case where it can help dramatically is when the MySQL server is a long way from the client *and* you can bundle together multiple SQL statements in the SP.  In this situation, you are cutting down on the network latency of multiple roundtrips.  That is, the SP, itself, is not providing any performance.
- An SP allows you to do looping.  But this is *usually* a bad programming practice for SQL.  Doing actions en masse with SQL can be an order of magnitude faster than, say, acting on one row at a time.
- If there is any enhancement in "compiling" the SP, it is minor, at least compared to the two items above.
- Having two 'identical' tables and having to pick between them (or `UNION` them) is *usually* a clumsy and inefficient schema design.  Avoid it where practical.  (In your example, had a single table with an extra column specifying the currency.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you can see in my question. There is overhead. I'm forming each query in Nodejs and send it to mysql (running on aws) server. As it involves network traffic also, SP should be an ideal way handling it. I do understand about the structure or design of the DB but It is not in my control. Unfortunately, I have to live with `how it is designed`.

Comment: @micronyks - Why do you "have to live with it"?  Too much work to change the design?  A boss that doesn't want change?  Lack of other job opportunities?

Answer (score 1):

The first things, you'll need are table and column names (I'll use CTEs to explain it step by step):

```
WITH tab_col_names AS (
    SELECT name, 
           tablename, 
           concat('c', row_number() over (order by id)) as colname
      FROM currency_table
)
SELECT * FROM tab_col_names;
```

| name | tablename | colname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rupee | rupee_table | c1 |
| Dollar | dollar_table | c2 |

Using this CTE, we can construct the SQL statement.

```
WITH tab_col_names AS (
    SELECT name, tablename, concat('c', row_number() over (order by id)) as colname
      FROM currency_table
)
SELECT concat(
         'SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) AS RESULT FROM (', 
           group_concat(
             concat('SELECT json_object("name", "', 
                    name, 
                    '", "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt), ',
                    colname, 
                    '))) AS obj FROM ', 
                    tablename,
                    ' where dt between "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z" AND "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z"'
             ) 
             SEPARATOR ' UNION '
           ), ') x'
         )  FROM tab_col_names
```

I put each argument of the inner concat on a separate line to make things more clear. For each record in tab_col_names, the inner concat constructs a string containing a SQL statement. The group_concat concatenates all those strings using the given separator `' UNION '` which gives us a single record. This is 'enclosed' by the outer SELECT statement using the outer concat.

The result is a long statement:

| result |
| --- |
| SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) AS RESULT FROM (SELECT json_object("name", "Rupee", "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt), c1))) AS obj FROM rupee_table where dt between "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z" AND "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z" UNION SELECT json_object("name", "Dollar", "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt), c2))) AS obj FROM dollar_table where dt between "2020-04-23T7:19:00Z" AND "2020-07-23T7:19:00Z") x |

In this example, the datetime range is still hardcoded. Having a stored procedure, we can replace them by the procedure's parameters and as parameters. Luckily, there's no risk of SQL injection since parameters are typed, so we can inject the parameters directly:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE all_currencies(dt_from datetime, dt_until datetime) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE query TEXT;
  WITH tab_col_names AS (
    SELECT name, tablename, concat('c', row_number() over (order by id)) as colname
      FROM currency_table
  )
  SELECT concat('SELECT json_arrayagg(obj) AS RESULT FROM (', group_concat(concat('SELECT json_object("name", "', name, 
        '", "value", json_arrayagg(json_array(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt), ', colname, '))) AS obj ' 
        'FROM ', tablename,
        ' where dt between ''', dt_from, ''' AND ''', dt_until, '''') SEPARATOR ' UNION '), ') x')  
      INTO query
    FROM tab_col_names;
  SET @q := query;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
```

Having this, you can call the procedure using datetime values:

```
CALL all_currencies('2007-04-01 00:00:00', '2007-06-30 00:00:00');
```

which results in

| RESULT |
| --- |
| [{"name": "Rupee", "value": [[1177312740, 10], [1179904740, 20], [1182586740, 30]]}, {"name": "Dollar", "value": [[1177312740, 100], [1179904740, 200], [1182586740, 300]]}] |

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jmboY_cf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just checked. Let me verify and come back to you.

Comment: @micronyks, I've added a link to a fiddle to my answer.