# how to get count of country column and as per count value, get result from other table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I have below tables

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to combine the result from two tables.

As you can I have **country** column which contains a string value (max two countries not more than two). If we can split the string, resultant array should contain two elements and we can count the elements as below.

For example,

> Rupee => india/nepal => if you split by "/", ["india", "nepal"] => count = 2

> dollar => usa/canada => if you split by "/", ["usa","cananda"] => count = 2

> yen  => japan => (?) , ["japan"] =>  count = 1

Now this count value is stored in **y_table** and as per the count value, I want to get other columns in the result set.

So what should be the query to get result as below,

[image]

Comment: That is a really poor and flimsy way of linking 2 tables. Please have a serious rethink

Comment: I can't control it. This is how it is designed unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables with a `CASE` expression in `the` ON clause that checks whether the value of the column `country` contains a `'/'` or not:

```
SELECT x.*, y.*
FROM x_table x INNER JOIN y_table y
ON y.count = CASE INSTR(x.country, '/')
  WHEN 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 2
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QqJRw7FJ).

Comment: Can you pls pls pls help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944429/stored-procedure-to-get-a-desire-result-set-to-improve-performance-mysql ?